# How do I copy names marked with an asterisk * from one column to another another?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a list of student names in Column A. I need to copy the names that are followed by an asterisk `*`  (I've highlighted them in the screenshot) into the `* Seniors` column D. Is there a formula I can use?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/171105/269219) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` and `search()`, like this:

```
=filter(A2:A, search("~*", A2:A))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [search()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154).

Answer (score 0):

use find() to search the *,
FIND("*";A2)
it return a number and then use isNumber(), to check it,
ISNUMBER(FIND("*";A2));A2;"")
if true return cell, if not return ""
and the last, use array formula to fill all cell below it (all cell below it must empty from value and formula)
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*";A2:A));A2:A;""))

[image: array formula]

so you not need to add or copy the formula again

or if you use